# Is type checking required for languages with full type inference (without type annotations)?

Tags: types, type-inference, language-design, typechecking

I'm new in type systems and type inference. My goal is to implement static type system and type inference algorithm for OOP language without types (the close example is JS without dynamic features like reflection and introspection).

My first idea was to implement static type system and type checking algorithm, and then implement type inference for this system. I've checked several articles about type inference ([Object-oriented type inference](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/117954.117965), [Type inference for static compilation of JavaScript](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3022671.2984017), [Type Inference of SELF](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/646151.679369)) and they all skip the type checking part, so I'm a little confused about my idea.

The main question is: how is type inference related to type checking? Do we need to do a type check after type inference? How is this implemented in existing languages with type inference (fully and partial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven’t actually implemented a static type system, but here’s how I would currently make a distinction between type inference and type checking:

Type inference assigns a set of types for parts of the program without explicit types. This process could fail if the type of part of the program is ambiguous and/or contradictory in a way that the compiler/interpreter cannot deal with.

We can use a slightly more generic term “Type Assignment” to include both types assigned via inference and through explicit annotations.

Type checking confirms that the pieces of the program fit together properly, regarding types. This can happen after all the type assignment for the given pieces are done. For example, If a given function has a given type assigned, in many languages it is still syntactically possible to call it with values with incorrect types.

Note that it would be possible to write an implementation where type inference and type checking are mixed together, but it isn’t necessary to do that. For example, given a program with a function `foo` calling a function `bar`, `foo` and bar could have their types assigned and the callsite type checked before moving on to the rest of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it became a little clearer to me. But I still don't understand if it's a good practice to first implement a static type system with type checking (and explicit annotation), and then add type inference to this system. This is the only approach that is available to me, because it seems too difficult for me to implement the type system with type inference "out of the box". Can you tell me please, where to read more about this? I would like to know how this happens in existing languages (Haskell, Ocaml). I need an understanding of the stages of type inference.

Comment: Hindley-Milner type inference is a particular algorithm that I hear talked about a lot, and which appears to have a lot written about it. While doing a search for it, I saw this page with a comment suggesting some different named algorithms instead: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15054752 I think it may make sense to compare some of these different algorithms and decide which of them to dig into further and eventually decide how to implement your own based on that research.